How do i fix this error OSError: source code not available
I am having an os error, i am trying to build a basic app from scratch in jupyter notebook, i am quite new to this
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.button import Button

class childApp(GridLayout):
    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        super(childApp,self).__init__()
        self.cols=2
        self.add_widget(Label(text="student name"))
        self.s_name=Textinput()
        self.add_weight(self.s_name)
        
        self.add_widget(Label(text="student marks"))
        self.s_marks=Textinput()
        self.add_weight(self.s_marks)
        
        self.add_widget(Label(text="student gender"))
        self.s_gender=Textinput()
        self.add_weight(self.s_gender)
        
        self.press=Button(text="click me")
        self.press.bind(on_press=self.click_me)
        self.add_widget(self.press)
        
    def click_me(self, instance):
        print("Name of student is "+self.s_name.text)
        print("Mark of student is "+self.s_marks.text)
        print("Gender of student is "+self.s_gender.text)
        print("")
    

class parentApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return childApp()

if __name__=="__main__":
    parentApp().run()

This is meant to give me an output where i can see a grid layout and input students name marks and gender

Don't make us guess where the error happens.  Please edit the question and add the full error traceback message.

See Alexander's comment in reply to 'Kivy in Jypiter notebook: OSError: source code not available' and here and here. If you want to build an app in Jupyter, then build in with UI components compatible with Jupyter, such as ipywidgets, Solara, etc.. Otherwise use Python directly so that you can have your UI handled by Kivy.

Also see this answer here from 10 months ago saying, "Kivy is not working in jupyter notebook environment as far as I know", and goinf on to see they switched to using Python directly. I'd tag  this for closing as a duplicate of the post 'Kivy in Jypiter notebook: OSError: source code not available' since it is the same exact error; however, I know that as there is no good answer there yet, SO won't let me.

For next time, please read How do I ask a good question?. Much of what John Gordon and myself point out here would have been covered if you had followed the guide sections 'Search, and research' and 'Help others reproduce the problem', with the addition of adhering to the statement 'Include any error messages'. Additionally, examining some of the other questions I reference hopefully gives you a sense of how your post fell short of being a good post. And please don't take these suggestions personally; just trying to make it easier for all involved.
